# Form action by drop down value in form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Am having form i need to form action by user selected value in drop down

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="city/<?drop_down_value?>/mobile.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<select name="Location" required="required">
<option value="">..</option>
<option value="india">india</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

when user selects option in form that value should be entered in form 
how do i make that

Comment: can we have drop down in form action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this...

```
<form id="frmLoginRegister" action="city/<?drop_down_value?>/mobile.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<select name="Location" required="required" id='Location' onchange="check(this.value)">
<option value="">..</option>
<option value="india">india</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function check(vak)
{
    $("#frmLoginRegister").attr("action", "city/"+ vak +"/mobile.php");
}
</script>
```

OR CAN TRY :

```
<form id="frmLoginRegister" action="city/<?drop_down_value?>/mobile.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<select name="Location" required="required" id='Location'>
<option value="">..</option>
<option value="india">india</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$("select").on('change',function() {
    $("#frmLoginRegister").attr("action", "city/"+ $(this).val() +"/mobile.php");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
$('form').attr('action', 'city/' + $(this).val() + '/mobile.php');
    //alert($('form').attr('action'));
});
```

Working [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/kqq9h7w3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can using Jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('select[name="Location"]').change(function(){
                console.log($(this).val());
                $('form[name="form"]').attr('action', 'city/' + $(this).val() + '/mobile.php');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <select name="Location" required="required">
        <option value="">..</option>
        <option value="india">india</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to select action

```
$("#selectid").change(function(){
    var goaction = $(this).val();
    alert(goaction);
    $("#yourform").attr("action",goaction);
});
```